# Fixed position view content after add new message (element)

Tags: javascript, html, css, structure, skype

**Task**:

Make a chat on Skype in HTML.

**Problem**:

No scrolling content after adding a new message.

**Description**:

There is a common site structure: header, content and footer. It is necessary that the content would be "hiding" under the header, but in the visible part of the window remained only part of the content (lower (message history on Skype)).
When you add a new message, the content must scrolling up to the height of this, new messages, and the message should appear at the bottom of the central block of the site (content), but should not go under the footer.

In this case it shall remain possible scrolling.

**HTML**:

```
<body>
<div id="header">HEADER</div>
<div id="sidebar" class="f_left">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div id="container" class="f_right">
  <div id="wrap3">
    <div id="wrap2">
      <div id="wrap1">
        <div id="content">
          <div id="im_nav_wrap">asdasdasdasd</div>
          <div id="im_content">
            <div class="im_rows_wrap">
            <div id="im_rows" class="im_peer_rows">
                <div class="mes">sddsfsdfsdfsdf</div>
                <div class="mes">sdfdfsdf</div>
                <div class="mes">fsdfsdf</div>
                <div class="mes">sdfsdf</div>
                <div class="mes">fsdfsdf</div>
                <div class="mes">fdsfsdfsdf</div>
                <div class="mes">fdsfsdfsdf</div>
            </div></div>
          </div>
          <div id="im_footer_wrap">
            <textarea name="dialog" id="im_textarea" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
            <button onclick="IM.send(this);">submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
  width: 980px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 40px;
  background: #cdcdcd;
}
#sidebar {
  top: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
  position: fixed;
}
.f_right {
  width: 600px;
  float: right;
}
#content {

}
#im_nav_wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #ff0ccc;
}
#im_content {
  padding: 120px 0 150px ;
}
#im_rows {

}
.im_rows_wrap {
   position: relative;
}
#im_rows {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 80px;
  width: inherit;
}
.mes {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#im_footer_wrap {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.im_rows_wrap').height($('#im_rows').height());
});

IM = {
  send: function(el) {
    var ta = $(el).prev('textarea').val();

    if (ta) {
      $('#im_rows').append('<div class="mes">' + ta + '</div>');

      $('.im_rows_wrap').height($('.im_rows_wrap').height() + $( ".mes" ).last().height())
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/CLzfW/7/
```

Using a bit of jQuery

```
$('.button').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    $('.expander').slideToggle();
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 'slow');
});
```

It scrolls to the bottom of the div on an event click (e.g button click, new message) and you also want a scroll bar on it?

Comment: Excluded. You can not use JQuery auto-scroll. In the future, it will create a big problem. It is advisable to do everything in pure CSS + manipulation of tall containers on JS.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start doing that without any JavaScript sorry